# Spring Boot 1.5.2.RELEASE: JDBC template Insert only if record doesnt exist

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have below groovy method which checks if record already exists or not and inserts only if record doesnt exist

```
 public insertRecord(senderId,recipientId,referenceId){
        logger.info("inserting digsig record ${referenceId}")
        TransactionDefinition txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus txStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(txDef);
        try {
            String selectSQL = "SELECT top 1 ID from parcels where reference_id =?";
            Integer name = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(selectSQL,[referenceId] as Object[], Integer.class);
            if(!name) {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO parcels (sender_id, recipient_id, reference_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
                jdbcTemplate.update(sql, senderId, recipientId, referenceId);
                transactionManager.commit(txStatus);
            }
            else{
                logger.info("reference_id $referenceId already exists in parcels")
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            transactionManager.rollback(txStatus);
            logger.error("Exception in insertRecord : Message = ${e.message} | Stacktrace: ${e.stackTrace}")            
        }
    }
```

It works only if a record already exists in `parcels` but if there is no existing record its failing with `Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0` exception message, can someone help me to make it work if a record doesnt exist?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the DBMS you are using doesn't handle `MERGE` or `UPSERT` sql statements, you can handle this with a stored procedure (ick!) or two JDBC calls.

First, try an update, assuming that the row exists:

```
int numberOfRecordsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE ... WHERE id = ?", ... , id);
```

You can then check `numberOfRecordsAffected`, if the value is `0` then this means that there wasn't a pre-existing record, and you can insert it as normal:

```
if (numberOfRecordsAffected == 0)
   jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT ... ", id, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of JdbcTemplate#queryForObject explicitly states:

> IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException - if the query does not return exactly one row, or does not return exactly one column in that row

So if you don't want to get that exception, you have to use a different method, which doesn't throw that exception. That could be for example

```
JdbcTemplate#queryForList(String sql, Class<T> elementType)
```

Then you would have to check for the list size to see if there was a result. If there were no results, the list would just be empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data problem and should be solved at data side.
If i understand correctly you want to insert only if the given reference Id is not present. Then you can make it a Unique key and use Insert Ignore to ignore if id is already present there by not going to db twice.